# Ergodic Theory: Why is $\frac{V_i(n)}{n} < \frac{Vi}{n} \to 0 = \frac{1}{m_i}$?

Tags: markov-chains, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to understand the Ergodic Theorem, but the book doesn't explain a step in this calculation. I understand the first step, and I understand the reason for why it converges to $0$, but what I don't understand is why this is equal to $\frac{1}{m_i}$.

Is it enough with just a simple intuitive explanation of this. The parameters are:

$V_i(n)$ = Visits in $i$ before $n$

$V_i$ = Total number of visits before $i$

$m_i = E_i(T_i)$ = Expected time to return to state $i$

> $\frac{V_i(n)}{n} < \frac{Vi}{n} \to 0 = \frac{1}{m_i}$

Comment: You should outline the Ergodic Theorem as set out by your book and illustrate why you understand the first step, which we can't see. You say something converges to $0$, but what is it? You should be specific.

Comment: Daniel's comment is spot on, as this problem is not well described.  However,  I will make some assumptions: I will assume that you have a discrete time Markov chain, that $i$ is a particular state, and taht $m_i$ is the mean recurrence time to state $i$ (given we start there).  Then, assuming we start in state $i$, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} V_i(n)/n = 1/m_i$ with prob 1 by standard renewal theory. So the $1/m_i$ was on the wrong side of your inequality.  Yes, books do have typos and mistakes.   I have no idea what $V_i$ means in your description, or what that inequality means.

Comment: Perhaps $V_i$ is intended to mean the total number of times we visit state $i$, considering all time.  Usually $V_i=\infty$, but perhaps the book is considering a case where $V_i$ is finite with prob 1, such as when state $i$ is transient.  In that case we have $V_i(n) \leq V_i$ for all $n$ (inequality is $\leq$ not $<$).  And indeed $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} V_i/n=0$, _but only if one first proves that $V_i$ is finite with prob 1_. The limit argument would then prove $m_i=\infty$, although that is also obvious if we already know there is a positive probability of never returning.

Comment: Ye it is like you said last. But what I don't understand is why $\frac{V_i}{n}=\frac{1}{m_i}$ in this case. I don't grasp that in my head. Sorry for not giving a better description.

Comment: It is certainly not true that $V_i/n=1/m_i$.  The left-hand-side depends on $n$, while the right-hand-side does not.  However, if you know that $V_i(n)/n \leq V_i/n$ for all $n$, you can take limits of both sides to conclude that, with prob 1,  $$\underbrace{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} V_i(n)/n}_{1/m_i} \leq \underbrace{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} V_i/n}_{0}$$ [the values in the underbraces assume that we start in state $i$, and that we know $V_i$ is finite with prob 1].

Comment: Okay thanks! Gotta look into that renewal theory thing to understand the limit otherwise I think I got it. Thanks! : >